# Wordpress - password redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, passwords

I want to issue customers with multiple unique passwords and for them to then visit a Wordpress page with a password box on it, and when they enter their password, to be directed to a specific URL linked to that password.
There could be 100's of unique passwords linking to maybe 20 URL's so I'll need to set up this 'many-to-one' relationship of course.
All ideas gratefully welcomed...

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading [ask] and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.